# Solucionado Problemas al insertar datos en PHP con PDO, realizado con MVC y POO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Vengo de varios intentos de registro y lo logré, ya me registra perfectamente en mi base de datos.
El problema no era la bd ni nada sino la forma en que preparaba los datos en el bindParem();

**Les dejare como solucioné esto en la parte de abajo,**
**Doy muchas gracias a quienes intentaron ayudarme, y no sé como poner en el post, solucionado**

clase del controlador

**public function registrarEgresado() {**

```
    if (isset($_POST['registroNombre'])) {

        $this->registroModelo= new Registro($_POST['registroNombre'],$_POST['registroApellido'],$_POST['registroDocumento'],$_POST['registroTipoDeDocumento'],$_POST['registroCorreo'],$_POST['registroCelular'],$_POST['registroDireccion'],$_POST['registroDepartamento'],$_POST['registroCiudad']);

        $resultado = $this->gestorRegistro->registrarEgresadoBD($this->registroModelo,"egresados_sena.registro_egresados");

        if ($resultado == "success") {
            echo "Registrado Correctamente.";
        }else{
            echo "El Registro Falló.";
        }
    }
}
```

Cree un objeto de la clase registro para enviar los datos como parametros al constructor de la clase registro y usar ese objeto creado como un array.

**$this->registroModelo= new Registro($_POST['registroNombre']..etc);**

Luego creo una variabe $resultado, que es aquella que trae el valor retornado en el modelo, la cual sera = al objeto de la clase del modelo la cual asigna la function **registrarEgresadoBD**, esta lleva como parametros el objeto con todos los datos y el "nombre de la tabla" que es un String.

Luego desde el modelo, en el constructor sigo teniendo la misma instancia de mi conexion tal cual como la cree desde el principio.

**private $instance;
private $conexion;**

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->instance = Conexion::getVerification();
    $this->conexion = $this->instance->getConexion();
}
```

Despues de tener instanciada mi conexion en la variable **$this->conexion**
Accedo a terminar mi funcion de registrar con PDO.

**public function registrarEgresadoBD(Registro $registroModelo, $tabla){**

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla(registro_egresados_nombre, registro_egresados_apellido, registro_egresados_numero_documento, cod_tipo_documento, registro_egresados_correo, registro_egresados_celular, registro_egresados_direccion, cod_departamento, cod_ciudad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try{

        $PrepareStatement = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(1, $registroModelo->getNombre());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(2, $registroModelo->getApellido());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(3, $registroModelo->getNumeroDocumento());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(4, $registroModelo->getCodTipoDocumento());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(5, $registroModelo->getCorreo());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(6, $registroModelo->getCelular());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(7, $registroModelo->getDireccion());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(8, $registroModelo->getCodDepartamento());
        $PrepareStatement->bindParam(9, $registroModelo->getCodCiudad());

        if ($PrepareStatement->execute()) {
            return "success";
        }else{
            return "error";
        }

    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error: ".$e;
    }

}
```

Así fue como logre Registrar en mi base de datos con PDO Y POO en PHP

**Vuelvo a comentar muchisimas gracias a quien colaboró.**

Comment: Tal y como se muestra en el error, el problema está en el $this que estas usando, aunque por que usas un this?

Comment: Por que yo pongo en la function $conexion y me dice que es una variable no definida.   Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ProyectoEgresadoSena\modelo\GestorRegistro.php on line 16   y ademas de eso... exactamente para la misma linea.

Comment: El error es claro: estás usando `$this` fuera de un contexto de objeto. Para usar la conexión simplemente tienes que instanciar tu clase `Conexion` e invocar el método que te retorna el objeto PDO que sería `getConexion()`. O sea, algo así donde necesites la conexión: `$mCon=new Conexion();`  y luego `$pdo=$mCon->getConexion();` y usar `$pdo` para todas las operaciones que tengas que hacer... Aunque tienes un poco de lío en tu clase, pero ese es otro tema...

Comment: Hola. ¿has probado la clase `conexion` dentro de otros métodos?

Comment: Si, claro, en ese formulario tengo 3 select en la vista del formulario, los cuales estan cargados con consultas de la bd, estas consultas las hice desde otra clase==archivo php, y me trae la consulta como es debido.

Comment: el compañero de mas arriba me formulo una buena pregunta... no creo que deberia de haber un error en si, por que cuando cargo consultas en la vista, yo tengo instanciada la conexion de la misma forma en que la instancio en esta clase,Ademas si estuviera mal, por que me trae consultas en los select? y no me deja registrar, no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es claro: estas usando `$this` fuera del contexto. Pero usas `$this` en varios lados ¿cual esta mal?.

El error esta en esta linea:

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->user, $this->pass);
```

¿Y cual `$this` esta mal?
Primero hay que explicar que es la **expansión de variables en php**.
En php puedes hacer esto:

```
$var="algo";
echo "Imprimiendo ".$var; //Imprimiendo algo
```

También lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
$var='algo';
echo 'Imprimiendo '.$var; //Imprimiendo algo
```

Pero en PHP existe la **expansión de variables**; *que es la capacidad que tiene php de resolver una variable al valor que contiene, dentro de una cadena*. Eso quiere decir que puedes hacer esto:

```
$var="algo";
echo "Imprimiendo $var"; //Imprimiendo algo
```

Pero ojo, la expansión de variables solo funciona con comillas dobles. Entonces si haces esto no funciona:

```
$var='algo';
echo 'Imprimiendo $var'; //Imprimiendo
```

Es por esta razón que *se considera buena practica de programación* usar `"` para las cadenas y en la medida de lo posible trato de que cualquier cadena se haga con  `"` en vez de `'` y así lo hago en cualquier lenguaje de programación incluso en `javascript` donde considero hacer cadenas con `'` una mala practica de programación.

¿Y todo esto que tiene que ver con tu problema?
Pues resulta que si quieres hacer expansión de variables con una propiedad de un objeto por ejemplo:

```
echo "El host: $this->host";
```

No funciona y te sale el error que estas experimentando. ¿Como resolver esto? Puedes hacer esto:

```
echo "El host: ".$this->host;
```

Entonces ¿la expansión de variables no funciona con objetos?
La respuesta es si, pero tienes que usar una sintaxis como esta:

```
echo "El host: {$this->host}";
```

Entonces volviendo a tu problema tu conexión debe ir así:

```
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->user, $this->pass);
```

Comment: Amigo, la verdad, la conexion esta bien, ya tengo he traido consultas con esa conexion, y funciona perfectamente

Comment: Ademas de eso, logré solucionar el registro y ya me funciona correctamente, voy a editar el post para que vean mi solucion.